# Eclipse plugin for angular not working

Tags: angularjs, eclipse

cant make the plugin

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started

work, not sure why though. have followed all instructions to the T.

although angular module is installed, the problem is i cant see any angular editor.

Please help

Comment: There's no "Angular Editor" on that page, just the regular `HTML Editor` that it's augmenting behind the scenes. You should see an `Angular Explorer`, though.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the project created in eclipse--> configure--> convert to Angular project, you will be able to get content assist for angular directives or elements on the html file now.